# how to remove field name in kendo grid grouping?

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I am angular 5 in my test application with @progress/kendo-angular-grid, i am trying to displaying group title. like Unit Price: 10, only i need to display 10.
as per kendo documentation example only i working can you please help me on that.

### link:

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/grouping/grouping/

above link show unit price: 10 , i want remove 'unit price:', only i need to display 10 .

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the group-header by nesting a `ng-template` with the `kendoGridGroupHeaderTemplate` directive within the `kendo-grid-column` tag.

```
<kendo-grid ...>
    <kendo-grid-column ...>
        <ng-template kendoGridGroupHeaderTemplate>
            <!-- Custom content here -->
        </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

More detailed information can be found in the [API Reference](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/GroupHeaderTemplateDirective/).

I've also created an [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/4C4oioCe2zZ9IYwXfkwj?p=preview) based on your description.